# ray optics irradiance map

Tags: python, 2d, histogram, weighted

I want to get an irradiance map of rays with powers p hitting a target at arbitrary positions (x,y). The target should be like a pixel sensor with pixels  of a certain edge length l. So, each pixel defines an area of l**2 and position (X,Y) of the target and has a value P that is the sum of the ray powers incident on this area. How can I get P(X,Y) from p(x,y)?

Answer (score 0):

Given an input field distribution say p(x,y) you can propagate this to an output field P(X,Y) via,

```
P(X,Y,z,t) = A(z)\int \int \int  p(x,y,z=0,f) exp(-ikR(x,y,X,Y,z))}R(x,y,X,Y,z) d x d y d f
```

Every point P(X,Y) at Z=z is the summation of every point on p(x,y,z=0) multiplied by a phase term. This phase term has the R in it which can be thought of as the radial distance between the two pixels.

Depending on your length scales and required resolutions etc this can be approximated to an FFT,

P(X,Y,z,t) = Prefactor \int FFT{p(x,y,z=0,f)*Slowphase} df

Make sense?